# Navigation Due to conditions, does not work as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

everyone.
I have a problem with forwarding within my React application.
the following:
I have a login page (SignIn.js) where the user can login with Google Auth (firebase).
That all works too.
But now it's the case that I don't want to remove the user every time after reloading the page. Because of this I use redux-persist.
The problem is now the navigation in my App.js.
If currentUser exists, then Home should be displayed to me and not the login page.
And vice versa.
But that doesn't work.
CurrentUser is null, see picture, but there is no login page.

My App.js site:

```
function App() {
const { currentUser } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

return (
 <div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <HeaderNav></HeaderNav>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <Route index element={<Home type="random" />} />
        <Route path="login" element={currentUser ? <Home /> : <Login />} />
        <Route path="articel">
          <Route path=":articelId" element={<SingleArticel />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
    <NavBar></NavBar>
  </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<Provider store={store}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
    <App />
  </PersistGate>
 </Provider>
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

[image]

redux-store.js

```
const persistConfig = {
key: "root",
version: 1,
storage,
};
 const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer });

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
reducer: persistedReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
getDefaultMiddleware({
  serializableCheck: {
    ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
  },
 }),
 });

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

An my userSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
 currentUser: null,
 loading: false,
 error: false,
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
name: "user",
initialState,
reducers: {
loginStart: (state) => {
  state.loading = true;
},
loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.currentUser = action.payload;
},
loginFailed: (state) => {
  state.loading = false;
  state.error = true;
},
 logout: (state) => {
  state.currentUser = null;
  state.loading = false;
  state.error = false;
  },
},
});

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailed, logout } =
userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

The local storage is available. IN this case, currentUser = null. Now the login mask should come up, but after a refresh of the page, it doesn't. I'm still on the home

[image]

Comment: So is your redux state not getting persisted to localStorage? Is the redux store not hydrated correctly? Can you share the redux code that creates/configures the store and the persistence?

Comment: Ok, added the redux store

Comment: The redux code appears fine. Have you checked that state is persisted to localStorage?

Comment: Hi. Yes, this one exists see original post

Comment: And when a user logs in? Does the redux state update as expected? Is the updated state persisted?

Comment: Actually no. But how come?

Comment: Nothing seems overtly out-of-place. Think you could create a basic *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?